# jQueryUI droppable, stop propagation to overlapped sibling

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/rA4CB/6/

When I make the drop in the overlapped area it is received in both droppables, greedy doesn't work when the items are siblings. Is there any way to block the reception on droppables lower in the zIndex?

BTW, mouseOver won't fire for the droppable element as the mouse is actually over the draggable element.

relevant JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        tolerance:'pointer',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
    $( "#droppable2" ).droppable({
        tolerance:'pointer',
        greedy:true,
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, so I spend an hour trying to figure it out, then as soon as I ask I then find my answer

http://jsfiddle.net/rA4CB/7/

Modified the JS to the following:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        tolerance:'pointer',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
    $( "#droppable2" ).droppable({
        tolerance:'pointer',
        greedy:true,
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        },
        over: function(event, ui){
            $( "#droppable" ).droppable( "disable" )
        },
        out: function(event, ui){
            $( "#droppable" ).droppable( "enable" )
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Clever - took me a while to see what you did there :-).   The over/disable and out/enable is a winner.
Thanks

Comment: Nice trick but not work for numbers of siblings. So see my above answer for this problem.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make the overlapped area un-droppable ?

Comment: The `out` isn't called if `drop` is called, so after the drop the `#droppable` will remain disabled.  I had changed `drop` to re-enable in the same way as `out` and that worked in 1.8, but in 1.11 it causes the propagation to happen again.

Comment: okay, above comment isn't quite true...  It works most of the time, but in some special cases I can't quite figure out it doesn't work any more.  In those cases, the 2nd 'drop' handler is called when the first re-enables and then finishes.

Answer (score 6):

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    greedy: true,
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
       if(ui.helper.is(".dropped")) {
           return false;
       }
       ui.helper.addClass(".dropped");
    }
});
```

Just set a css class on ui.helper of draggable. If the draggable has been accepted once, it will be refused by all other droppables (Could be done with the droppable "accept" parameter,too , like `accept : ":not(.dropped)"` and the class added to ui.draggable).

Comment: this should be accepted answer. Only problem is you need to remove the period from the addClass call: addClass("dropped"); I used classname "accepted". only thing that works well.

Comment: Removing the `dropped` class in `activate` will also allow it to be dragged again.

Comment: This works great if you use `helper: "clone"` on the draggable, but if it's the default (which is `"original"`) then the draggable will always be marked as "dropped" and won't work any more.

Comment: This technique is solid, but instead of using a class I added an attribute to `event.originalEvent` and then tested for that.  That will work regardless of the `helper` setting.  Unfortunately, the order drop methods are called aren't related to the z-index so even that solution may not be enough if it matters which is called first.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **number of droppable** in a container area then what????

You must re think for that problem. **Greedy** works for only **parent to child relationship** not in **siblings**. So you must edit droppable js or put your own logic for it.

So if you have a numbers of droppable then you must write some extra code to handle dropping on perfect droppable as it is in this example [A number of siblings droppables](http://jsfiddle.net/rA4CB/58/)

For making perfect **siblings droppable** modify your **droppbale** as below

```
        var topElement = undefined;
        var topElementArray = Array();

        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( ".droppableBox" ).droppable({
            activeClass: "active-droppable",
            tolerance:'pointer',
            over: function( event, ui ) { 
                // This is for only show a message that z-index must be required for proppable
                // you can remove it after testing or after development
                if ($(this).css("z-index") == 'auto') {
                    alert("Please provide z-index for every droppable.");
                    return;
                }
                //

                topElement = undefined;
                topElementArray = Array();
                // Change it as you want to write in your code
                // For Container id or for your specific class for droppable or for both
                $('#demo > .droppableBox').each(function(){                     
                    _left = $(this).offset().left, _right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
                    _top = $(this).offset().top, _bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
                    if (event.pageX >= _left && event.pageX <= _right && event.pageY >= _top && event.pageY <= _bottom) {   
                          topElementArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
                    }
                });
            },
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                if (!topElement) {
                    topElement = determineTopElement(topElementArray);
                }                   
                if ($(this).attr('id') == $(topElement).attr('id')) {
                    $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" );
                  // Your code after successful dropped element on specific siblings
                  // Start writing code for dropped element & perfect droppable
                }

            }
        });

        determineTopElement = function(_array) {
            var topElement;
            var zIndexHighest = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < _array.length; i++){
               var element = $("#"+ _array[i]);
               var z_index = $(element).css("z-index");
               if( z_index > zIndexHighest){
                   zIndexHighest = z_index;
                   topElement = element;
               }
            }
            return topElement;       
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make the overlapped area un-droppable ?

Answer (score 1):

In certain circonstances :

```
myjQuery.droppable({
  over:function(evt,ui){
    ui.draggable.attr('drg_time', this.drg_time = evt.timeStamp)
  },
  accept:function(draggeds){
    if(draggeds.attr('drg_time'))
    {
      return draggeds.attr('drg_time') == this.drg_time
    }
    return draggeds.hasClass('acceptable_classes_here')
  },
  out:function(evt,ui){
    // useless but cleaner
    ui.draggable.removeAttr('drg_time')
  }
  drop:...,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and made a small plugin :)

check it out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16720944/1308461

Answer (score 0):

I find that using #invertedSpear's method will cause UI state change which is not desirable in some cases. Here is the code.

```
var lastOpertion = new Date().getTime();

drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (new Date().getTime() - lastOpertion < 100) return;
        lastOpertion = new Date().getTime();
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when trying to find simple solution I came up with this (and it works for me):

```
            window.overNowOnThis = "";
            window.olderOnes = [];
            $obj.droppable({
                accept: ".draggable_imgs",
                drop: function(e, ui) {
                    if(window.overNowOnThis == this){
                        // Do whatever
                    }
                },
                over: function(event, ui){
                    window.olderOnes.push(window.overNowOnThis);
                    window.overNowOnThis = this;
                },
                out: function(){
                    var lastElem = window.olderOnes.pop();
                    window.overNowOnThis = lastElem;
                }
            });
```

Top element would be selected because on it "over" fires the last one. Also - if there is more than two siblings - then when moving out of element we set the last one as current. Using global "window" was for example. Better option would be using classes as it can safely keep data.

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar to invertedSpear answer. I had to change it a little bit because enabling/disabling inside "over"/"out" didn't work for me .I had to do below instead

```
$("#droppable2").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $("droppable").droppable("disable");
    }
}
```

I had to explicitly enable"droppable" div when I needed it. For instance, enable it when starting the drag event. Eg

```
$("#drageMe").draggable({
 start:function(event,ui){
   $("droppable").droppable("enable");
```

}
})

Answer (score -1):

try greedy option in ui dropable. see the fiddle link below for demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/creators_guru/3vT5C/embedded/result/

```
$( ".circles" ).droppable({
    greedy: true,
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $_data  =   ('drgged class = ' + ui.draggable.attr('class'));
        $_data1 =   ('droped id = #' + $(this).attr('id'));
        $('#data').html($_data + '<br/>'+$_data1);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Right in my question I pointed out "Greedy doesn't work when the items are siblings"