# Stop drop event in Jquery drag&drop

Tags: jquery, dom, drag-and-drop

I have this problem using Jquery drag&drop. I have two div element stacked one over the other. The bottom div is droppable and bigger. If I dropp an item on the upper div the bottom div handles the dropp.

How to make div handle the drop only if the element is directly dropped on it.

I've tried using `stopPropagation()` on the upper div but that did not work.

Somekind of simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/e87wS/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer**

Use `over` and `out` to disable and enable the other div. `greedy` means the droppable area will be the only one that works and `tolerance: touch` means that as long as the draggable object is touching the droppable area it will drop there.

It would look like this:

```
$('#div2').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        alert("droppedHere");
    },
    greedy: 'true',
    tolerance: 'touch',
    over: function (event, ui) {
        $("#div1").droppable("disable")
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        $("#div1").droppable("enable")
    }
});

$('#div1').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){
        alert("droppedThere");
    }
});
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e87wS/15/

Comment: I need the red div to handle the drop. Then the tolerance option fails. http://jsfiddle.net/e87wS/8/ Gives you an aler even if dropped over the green!

Comment: could you explain a little more why the bottom div handles the drop? and how you were doing that?

Comment: Let's say the picture to drag should be placed on the green div... When you dragged it just a litle the red div accepts it. I want the red div to accept it only if dragged out of the green div.

Comment: OK i see the problem, I think my updated answer should at least point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in my case this doesn't work. Is it possible to capture the event on the green div and then somehow stop it propagating.

Comment: Found the sollution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997053/jqueryui-droppable-stop-propagation-to-overlapped-sibling