# Greedy not capturing the first event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/xVvZB/1/ - with two overlapping beige boxes that are droppable and a red box to drop onto the beige boxes. Even though I have "greedy" set true in the beige dropOps:

```
var beige_dropOps = {    
    drop : beigeDrop,       
    accept : '#redBox',     
    greedy : true
};
```

when the redBox is dropped on  them I get two calls to the drop handler, one for each beige box. So it appears that the drop event is not being captured by  the top box, as I expect with greedy = true. You can see the two interrupts by turning on Firebug and watching the debugger line in beigeDrop() gets called twice, once with this=box1 and once with this=box2.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: For your intended behavior, there is [a clever trick in a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997053/jqueryui-droppable-stop-propagation-to-overlapped-sibling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

greedy effects parent-child relationships, not sibling relationships.

[See This Fiddle For Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xVvZB/2/)

basically,

```
greedy:true
```

stops events from bubbling to parent elements.  In your example fiddle, the 2 elements are siblings so the function is fired twice.  In my example fiddle, box 2 is a child of box 1 so only box 2 fires the function.