# Keeping a box from dropping through to the lower of two sibling droppables

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/eswZS/1/ - with two sibling boxes that overlap and  are droppable.  I only want the redBox to drop into the top beige box when I drop it over the two but the tricks I know aren't working: the redBox always drops into the top beige box and then  crashes through to the bottom beige box.  I understand that UI greedy only works for parent-child boxes, so it won't capture the drop event here, but I thought e.stopPropagation() or return false might do it:

```
function beigeDrop(e, ui) {
    console.log("dropping into ", this);
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;   

}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Well `stopPropagation` and returning false only stop it from travelling up the DOM hierarchy. In this case the container of of all three divs won't get the drop event.

Comment: As I said in a comment to a question you asked earlier today, there is [this technique](http://jsfiddle.net/eswZS/3/)

Comment: @PauloAlmeida That's a nice solution. It makes box 1 undroppable whenever you are over box2. If the boxes aren't overlapping you don't need that but it doesn't hurt. If they are overlapping, it fixes the problem. It could be doable but confusing to handle, say, 5 boxes. Each would have to make all those before it in the DOM undroppable when you were over it. Making some classes like 'underBox2', 'underBox3', etc would help. If you added it here as an answer, I would upvote it.

Comment: @LeeMeador, Thanks, but it's not my solution, I got it from a previous [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997053/jqueryui-droppable-stop-propagation-to-overlapped-sibling). I linked to it when I first suggested it to Steve, but I guess he missed it, which is why I suggested again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

Change it to this because the drop events come in the order of the box elements in the DOM. The first one in the DOM appears below the second one. So the last drop event is actually the one on top.

When we set the very short timeout it gets put on the event queue after all the drop events. It doesn't matter that the timeout gets overwritten for each drop event. The last drop event stores the element into the variable and then the timeout is where we recognize the drop we care about. (I don't know if you want to save the 'ui' variable too.)

```
var droppedBox;
function beigeDrop(e, ui) {
    droppedBox = this;

    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        if (droppedBox) {
            console.log("dropping into ", droppedBox);
        }
        droppedBox = null;
    }, 1);
}
```

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eswZS/5/)

Note that if you mess with the 'z-layer' css value, it will change the way the boxes overlap but won't change the ordering of the boxes in the DOM and won't change the order of the drop events. (If you want to handle that case, store all the 'this' values for all elements dropped on. Use an array. Then, in the timeout you can sort through the array and find the one with the highers z-layer and use it as the 'dropped on' box.)

**Original Answer - See comment for problems**

You are telling it that both beige boxes will accept the red box being dropped on them. This will make the one box accept it but not the other:

```
$('#box1').droppable({drop:beigeDrop, accept:'#redbox'});
$('#box2').droppable({drop:beigeDrop, accept:'#none'});
```

[First MODIFIED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eswZS/2/)

Comment: No, I can't do that because both beige boxes have to be able to accept the red box. If you drag the beige boxes apart, for example, so they don't overlap, you should be able to drop the red box into either one, as, in fact, you can do with my jsfiddle. But when the beige boxes overlap, the user's intent is probably to only drop the red box into the top one, so that's what I want to do. I guess the rule I'm trying to implement is that you have to be able to "see" the beige box where you drop, before a drop into that box happens.

Comment: I didn't get that from the question. But, here you go. New answer taking that into account.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **number of droppable** in a container area then what????

You must re think for that problem. **Greedy** works for only **parent to child relationship** not in **siblings**. So you must edit droppable js or put your own logic for it.

So if you have a numbers of droppable then you must write some extra code to handle dropping on perfect droppable as it is in this example [A number of siblings droppables](http://jsfiddle.net/rA4CB/58/)

For making perfect **siblings droppable** modify your **droppbale** as below

```
        var topElement = undefined;
        var topElementArray = Array();

        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( ".droppableBox" ).droppable({
            activeClass: "active-droppable",
            tolerance:'pointer',
            over: function( event, ui ) { 
                // This is for only show a message that z-index must be required for proppable
                // you can remove it after testing or after development
                if ($(this).css("z-index") == 'auto') {
                    alert("Please provide z-index for every droppable.");
                    return;
                }
                //

                topElement = undefined;
                topElementArray = Array();
                // Change it as you want to write in your code
                // For Container id or for your specific class for droppable or for both
                $('#demo > .droppableBox').each(function(){                     
                    _left = $(this).offset().left, _right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
                    _top = $(this).offset().top, _bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
                    if (event.pageX >= _left && event.pageX <= _right && event.pageY >= _top && event.pageY <= _bottom) {   
                          topElementArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
                    }
                });
            },
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                if (!topElement) {
                    topElement = determineTopElement(topElementArray);
                }                   
                if ($(this).attr('id') == $(topElement).attr('id')) {
                    $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" );
                  // Your code after successful dropped element on specific siblings
                  // Start writing code for dropped element & perfect droppable
                }

            }
        });

        determineTopElement = function(_array) {
            var topElement;
            var zIndexHighest = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < _array.length; i++){
               var element = $("#"+ _array[i]);
               var z_index = $(element).css("z-index");
               if( z_index > zIndexHighest){
                   zIndexHighest = z_index;
                   topElement = element;
               }
            }
            return topElement;       
        }
```