# jquery droppable two return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, droppable

I have two images. The photo-1 partly covering the photo-2:
[2 photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vniu.jpg)

I can drop a new image on the photo-1 with jQuery draggable-droppable.
The problem is: if I drop the new photo on the photo-1, I get back two values sequentially.
(first: photo-1 id, second: photo-2 id)

Here is the code:

```
$("#dropbox span").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ){
        var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(droppableId);
    });
});

<div id="dropbox">
<span id="first"></span>
<span id="second" ></span>
</div>
```

How could I get back just the first id?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share your html script, without that we can't find a way to solve it

Comment: My question has been refreshed.

Comment: you have a syntax error in your js

Comment: I can solve the problem with this:
https://github.com/vaceta/jquery-top-droppable

Comment: @rastafest I think what you need is `event.stopPropagation()`, so that parent DIV `drop` will not be invoked when dropped on its child elements. Refer API DOC:http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Pruthvi Bharadwaj thanks for the suggestion. I tried but didnt work. Could you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem in two ways:

1. with a js:  [vaceta / jquery-top-droppable](http://github.com/vaceta/jquery-top-droppable)
2. with a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997053/jqueryui-droppable-stop-propagation-to-overlapped-sibling), but here I need to modify the 'over' section:  droppable({ disabled: true })

Thanks everyone for the help.