# jquery droppable on nested lists with same class

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I have a menu structure which I want to change dynamically. The menu could be listed like this.

```
<ul>
<li id="1/2" class='draggable'>
    <ul>
        <li id="1/3" class='draggable'>
        content
        </li>
        <li id="2/4" class='draggable'>
            <ul>
                <li id="5/2" class='draggable'>
                content
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="1/6" class='draggable'>
content
</li>
```

And the jquery code looks like this:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
});

$( ".draggable" ).droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    live: true,
    drop: function(event, ui) {

        var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        var droppableId = $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable).attr("id");
        alert(draggableId + droppableId);

    }

});
```

As you can see in the jquery code, I want to catch the dragged element, and the element where it's dropped. The problem here is that jquery runs the drop function in every nested list with the class draggable. **I only want to catch the deepest list item.**

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve but you may want to look at at similar question about [overlapping droppables here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997053/jqueryui-droppable-stop-propagation-to-overlapped-sibling).

Also, I'm guessing if you're trying to make a tree or menu, You may have better luck with [jQueryUI Sortable > Connected Lists](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

There's even a plugin (not part of jqueryUI) specifically for sorting menus/trees: [jQuery Sortable](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) (not to be confused with the above one, despite the same name)

Good luck!